# Unable to debug on ipad

Tags: ipad

I am facing very strange problem. 
On my mac machine which has xcode 3.2.5 installed with iOS SDK 4.2. I am working on a universal application that runs fine on iphone 4 [can debug too] but not on iPad. When I run the application on ipad in debug mode then the application stops at splash screen with no error in console.
I can run the application by tapping on the application icon on home screen in ipad but not through xcode.
What may be the reason behind it?
Thanks
Arnieterm

Answer (score 1):

Try restart the ipad. This is due to the debug process in ipad is sucked.

Answer (score 0):

Your build scheme may not be in debug... Check your build scheme..
In XCode 4, goto Product -> Edit Scheme, then set Scheme to 'Debug'...

Comment: I think you mean Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...   I tried this, but I'm having the same issue and this has not fixed my problem.